# Jquery on page load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a Get Request in PHP to get a certain value, I am then taking this value and inputting it into a textfield's value, I have that text-fields value then call a json request.

It works on input and change, but on page load. Here is the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var runningRequest = false;
    var request;
    $('input#asd3').on('load', function(e) {
        var $q = $(this);
         if(runningRequest){
             request.abort();
         }
         runningRequest=true;
         var myString = self.location.href;
         var mySplitResult = myString.split("?");
         request = $.getJSON('search',{q:$q.val()},function(data){  
             showResults(data,$q.val());
             showResults2(data,$q.val());           
             runningRequest=false;
         });
     });
 });
```

The html

```
   <input type="text" id="asd3" name="asd3" value="<?php echo $name ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Name..." class="input-block-level" placeholder="Search..."  style="width:100%; display:none;"  />
```

Comment: Why do you think an input element would have a load event?

Comment: @Taplar The input is a database ID. ie: 15. It used to be on change and we added this: $('#asd3').val(id).trigger("input"); But now we want to load the results of the page, "on load"

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

The load event is primarily related to elements that pertain to external resources.  The window document, images, iframes, etc.  An input element does not rely on anything like that and would not have a load event.

If you want the logic to happen on 'page' load then you should bind to the window or document.  Try changing...

```
$('input#asd3').on('load', ...
```

to

```
$(document).on('load', ...
```

Comment: Well, Thank you for that. How would you suggest that I write this?

Comment: And how would I get that textbox's value?

Comment: $('#asd3').val()  So far this answer only pertains to your attempted usage of the load event.  It may not result in your desired result.  If not, for a better answer it would be beneficial to have description of what is happening and what you would like to result.

Comment: I'd also suggest getting rid of `$('input#asd3').on('load', function(e) {` since you've already established that the DOM is ready.